# show a button and strike through only for that particular li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code, which works perfectly, except when it comes to nested LI elements that might be nested under the li element I am targeting:

```
$('#comment-section .comment-box a#un-do').hide();

$('#comment-section ul li[data-is-archived="true"]').map(function() {
  $('#comment-section ul li[data-is-archived="true"]').css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
  $('#comment-section ul li[data-is-archived="true"] a#un-do').show();
}).get();
```

What this will do is strike out any text in this li element, and show the undo link for each li element that matches this particular element (or set of).

```
ul
 li - strike through works, shows undo button, data-is-archived = true
  ul
   li - strike through works, shows undo button, data-is-archived = false
```

Why is every nested li element getting striked through and having a link appear when only the ones with `data-is-archived=true` should have the strike through and the link show up - as code states?

Comment: Using `map` in your code doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `text-decoration: strike-through` property applies to all text in the `<li>` element that has the HTML5 data attribute `is-archived` of the value `true`, regardless of whether the nested children fits the selector or not. I have replicated your problem in a JSfiddle (please do that yourself next time): http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/TZVej/1/

The solution would be to wrap the text within each `<li>` element with a `<span>` element, and apply that via restrictive, direct descendent-only CSS.

```
$('#comment-section .comment-box a#un-do').hide();
$('#comment-section ul li[data-is-archived="true"]').map(function() {
    // Target only <span> elements that are direct descendants
    $('#comment-section ul li[data-is-archived="true"] > span').css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
    $('#comment-section ul li[data-is-archived="true"] a#un-do').show();
}).get();
```

See proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/TZVej/2/

p/s: I am not sure why you are using the `.map()` function when there is no use for it in the question's context...

Comment: There is use for the `.map` function as there could be more then one li element scattered through out with the `data-is-archived` set to true. Also the ata inside the li elements i wrapped in a div.